# What sort of Power consumption should I be able to get down to when turning everything off

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My electricity consumption is higher than I would expect.
I have an old-school turn-y dial meter, so I can measure the power consumption of the house at any given time.

I tried going round and turning ***everything*** off.

- All the lights, obviously.
- All computers and other charging items.
- All sockets.
- All appliances. (incl. e.g. fridge and oven off at the socket)
- Boiler controls (actually heating is gas, but I guess there's pumping and clocks, etc.)

Now I wouldn't expect to *actually* get to zero - I'd expect there to be some trivial things that don't have switches (things like hard-wired thermostat controls, or a door bell, etc. etc. etc.), but I'd expect to be able to get damn close. 5s of Watts, maybe?

The lowest I could get was around 0.17kW. Which seems much higher than I would expect?

How low would you expect to be able to get your power consumption if you could turn everything off at the plug?

---

*House details:*

- *UK, London.*
- *3 bed, 2 story house.*
- *Early 1950's construction.*
- *Gas heating*

Comment: Do you possibly have some heat tape around the plumbing to keep it from freezing?

Comment: 170 watts is not much.  Would imagine something not turned off.  A small pump or fan for something.  Heating system might have fan/pump on to keep from overheating for some time after heat turned off(minutes)

Comment: To narrow down where the draw is coming from, you can flip off the circuit breakers one at a time in your consumer unit.  When the power draw stops, you've found which circuit it's on, which may give you a clue as to what is drawing the power.

Comment: Have you tried turning off a) the individual breakers in your consumer unit and measuring the power, then b) turning off the *main isolator* in your consumer unit and measuring the power again?

Answer (score 3):

Turning things off will not stop the power usage on many electronic devices, tv’s microwaves or anything with a touch pad to turn it on consumes power to keep the electronics alive watching for a button push.
Even power supplies to computers and cell phone chargers when not plugged in consume a small amount of power. How can you tell if your “wall wart” plug in transformer is using power? Feel it if it is warm or warmer than the surrounding area it is consuming power how much ??? It varies cable boxes computer routers are all things that add up. If everything is unplugged most homes can get down to 15-20w and these are hard wired transformers for door bells and furnaces. So you should be able to get down much further based on testing I Have done for customers.

Comment: OP is in the UK, where pretty much every socket has a switch on it which disconnects the device plugged in, and they mentioned they turned them all off, so I don't think it's phantom draw from wall warts in this case.

Comment: Nate good point I was not aware of that but if there cable boxes and routers are like mine I never turn them off because the reboot is lengthy and in some cases requires a password a dozen of these type of devices could add up to the total. But good point.

Comment: @Nate assuming they used that feature.

Comment: That's definitely what I intended to do. And definitely what I did for a majority of them. It was quite late when I did it, so it's possible that I forgot some and only turned the appliance "off". I'll try again and make more certain, and apply the circuit breaker suggestion.

Comment: But thank you for the confirmation of a target range!

Comment: @Brondahl interested in your progress. I disagree with one comment that 170W isn't much - it's a lot for a dead house. EDF fitted me a smart meter with a live power monitor, and I regularly consume less than 100W without turning things off, and I have a number of electronics including smart lights that are never actually powered down.

Comment: @sam_butler wow I am glad you disagree with your single case of almost 60% of the value I listed in a comment. Read the answer for a realistic minimum value and if you have a question ask it and others will answer. By the way,  My measurements were taken with ntsc certified equipment were yours?

Comment: @EdBeal just seen your comment from a few weeks back, apologies. It wasn't aimed at you at all, but at the OP, and referenced a comment made on the OP by crip659. I agree with your answer with respect to most homes being able to get down to 15-20W. The measurements I've seen in my home not far from the OP's were reported by a smart meter installed by the power company, manufactured by Toshiba to standards EN62053-21, EN50470-3 and IEC62052-31.

Comment: @sam_butler comments under an answer are about that answer normally, comments to the OP are under the question. That’s why I took it that way but thanks for explaining.